# Swift: ViewWillDisappear called when view appears

Tags: swift, viewcontroller, viewdidappear

I am writing a program in Swift, but I am getting a really strange error. Ok here is the problem:
I press a button from one viewcontroller and go to another viewcontroller (standard navigation controller - a new view is pushed onto the stack). In this new viewcontroller I have overriden the ViewDidDisappear. When i go back to the previous viewcontroller this is obviously called. BUT when I now go back to this viewcontroller again, the method is called when the view appears and a second after the app crashes! 
I get the following error:
`EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0))`

Comment: Can you post the code for the view controller? Specifically the view lifecycle methods would be interesting.

Comment: clean, recompile, retry - if the error persists, post code

Comment: I'm currently experience the exact same thing...in 2017